# Why does bxSlider break my transition between last and first slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I'm using bxSlider, for each slide I have several HTML elements not just an image. I need to make the active slide bigger than the others, I already accomplished that using css zoom and transition, but when I move from the first slide to the second slide or from the second one to the first one, my transition is missing, I mean it only grows up but it doesn't do the animation, it's ok for all the other slides, does anyone know why this transition breaks?

This is my code

```
$('#sliderTrend').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 300,
            minSlides: 1,
            maxSlides: 3,
            moveSlides: 1,
            slideMargin: 3,
            pager: false,
            onSliderLoad: function () {
                $('#sliderTrend>div:not(.bx-clone)').eq(1).addClass('active-slide');
                $('#sliderTrend>div:not(.bx-clone)').eq(1).removeClass('inactive-slide');
            },
            onSlideBefore: function ($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
                $('.slideC2').removeClass('active-slide');
                $('.slideC2').addClass('inactive-slide');
                $($slideElement).next().removeClass('inactive-slide');
                $($slideElement).next().addClass('active-slide');
            }
        });
```

And these are my css classes

```
.active-slide {
    zoom:100%;
    margin-top:0px;
    -moz-transition:  zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;
    -webkit-transition:  zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;
    -o-transition: zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;
    transition: zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;
}

.inactive-slide {
    zoom:75%;
    margin-top:60px;
    -moz-transition:  zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;
    -webkit-transition:  zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;
    -o-transition: zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;
    transition: zoom 150ms linear, margin-top 150ms linear;    
}
```

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle of your code ?

Answer (score 1):

## SO36637125

### Why does bxslider breaks my transition between last and first slide?

It's hard to be certain with bxSlider, it's a very flexible yet temperamental plugin. I believe it was the callbacks were too much. Every slider was removing and adding 2 classes all at once, which isn't healthy behavior for a single thread language like JavaScript.

When dealing with active and inactive states, you should know that bxSlider has it's own `.active` class and the active slider is always going to be the slide on the left, not the middle. So taking that into account, this is whats been done:

- Removed the `.inactive-slide` class. Instead of having two states to deal with, use an active state, and use the default state (which is how slides are normally).
- Changed the `.active-slide` class to `.act` because it saves time typing less. Changed the CSS rules to:

  ```
    .act {
       transition-duration: 1s;
       transition-timing-function: ease-in;
       transform: scale(2);
       transform-origin: center center;
       z-index: 9999999;
    }
  ```

  - Using `z-index` to overlap the slides to the right and left.
  - Notice there's no `position` property. That's because by default each slide is `position: relative`.

  -For details on the animation properties, you can find it [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/).
- Removed the `onSliderLoad` callback because it's flaky. I've used bxSlider for a couple of years, and I have only been able to get it to work a few times.
- Changed the `onSlideBefore` callback to simplify it:

  ```
    onSlideBefore: function($ele, from, to) {
       var $act = $ele.next();
       $act.addClass('act');
       $act.siblings().removeClass('act');
    }
  ```

  - The first line basically references the real active slider that is positioned on the left (i.e. `$ele`) and targets the next slide after the active slide so now the `.act` class will be assigned to the middle slide.
  - The second line `.addClass('act')` to the middle slide (i.e. `$act`).
  - The last line ensures that there's only one `$act` slide by using `.siblings()` to remove `.act` class from every slide except `$act`.
  - This works because there's only one class to handle.

### [README.md](http://plnkr.co/edit/CSZch1K8WPsfYBbjnoxX?p=info)

### [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/CSZch1K8WPsfYBbjnoxX?p=preview)